# Javascript createElement and adding className padding don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i add  `padding-:20px` , it's not working. 
I couldn't form the question and search on google.No results matched my problem.Can someone atleast provide me a link explaining the problem I am facing?

I also want to center the text.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("add-task");
btn.onclick = addingText


function addingText (list, itemTexts) {
 
 var input = document.getElementById("taks-input").value;
 var itemTexts = input;
 
    
    var taskList = document.createElement("span");
 taskList.className = "center";
    taskList.innerHTML = itemTexts;
    
   var list = document.getElementById("taskContent");
    list.appendChild(taskList);
 
 
}
```

```css
.chack {
    background-color: #4c4b62;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;     
}

.task-text {
    background-color: #55566e;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    
}

.color {
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fdcd63;
}

.task {
    height: 100px;
}

.chack,.color,.task-text{
    float: left;
}

.add-new-task {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(85, 86, 110);
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}


.center{
 padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="add-new-task">
   <input type="text" id="taks-input">
   <button id="add-task">Add New Task</button>
</div>
   
    <div class="task">
        <div class="col-3 chack"></div>
        <div class="col-8 task-text" id="taskContent"></div>
        <div class="col-1 color"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline elements don;t have padding...

Answer (score 0):

Taking what epascarello has said, I changed `var taskList = document.createElement("span");` into `var taskList = document.createElement("div");`

I added `text-align: center;` to `.task-text` to center text as requested

I changed `.center` by adding `margin: 30px auto 0;`

I changed `#taks-input` to `#task-input` because it bothered me. :P

Btw the `.task` is only 100px high. Do you plan to have more than 2 tasks?

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("add-task");
btn.onclick = addingText


function addingText (list, itemTexts) {
 
 var input = document.getElementById("task-input").value;
 var itemTexts = input;
 
    
    var taskList = document.createElement("div");
 taskList.className = "center";
    taskList.innerHTML = itemTexts;
    
   var list = document.getElementById("taskContent");
    list.appendChild(taskList);
 
 
}
```

```css
.chack {
    background-color: #4c4b62;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;     
}

.task-text {
    background-color: #55566e;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
    
}

.color {
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fdcd63;
}

.task {
    height: 100px;
}

.chack,.color,.task-text{
    float: left;
}

.add-new-task {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(85, 86, 110);
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}


.center{
    margin: 30px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="add-new-task">
   <input type="text" id="task-input">
   <button id="add-task">Add New Task</button>
</div>
   
    <div class="task">
        <div class="col-3 chack"></div>
        <div class="col-8 task-text" id="taskContent"></div>
        <div class="col-1 color"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```